# How can I compare tokenise word in two column in python data frame

Tags: python, string, nltk, token, summary

I have a CSV file that has a record of IT incidents.I have a 'summary' column and a  'category' column 
 I generated the tokenize word for each row in this column.I want to compare the token in the summary column with the category column

Comment: Could you please add some ponctuation? And, add an example of what your CSV looks like? How do you tokenised the summary? Which would be the comparison criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You're not really specific on how you want to compare your vectors but a common approach is to use Euclidean distance (L2 Norm).
I propose to extract your token columns to numpy array and then use [numpy.linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

```py
import numpy as np

# a and b would represent your token columns
# you didn't specify the size of each token/vector so I set it to 5 for the sake of this example
a = np.random.rand(4,5)
b = np.random.rand(4,5)
a, b

OUT:
(array([[0.39435087, 0.06389897, 0.66712442, 0.5442628 , 0.29284329],
        [0.10868951, 0.61121235, 0.24025041, 0.57043359, 0.1375542 ],
        [0.56818288, 0.74752492, 0.16356138, 0.79570418, 0.01905405],
        [0.44776656, 0.31403308, 0.29965215, 0.21162856, 0.49277446]]),
 array([[0.6300318 , 0.47202827, 0.19513324, 0.38156414, 0.85896642],
        [0.69856134, 0.33403423, 0.17599279, 0.62404711, 0.10093772],
        [0.18569367, 0.9487905 , 0.76287508, 0.30532111, 0.66589667],
        [0.88249761, 0.32604273, 0.95195868, 0.89162121, 0.03382068]]))

# this will be a per row distance between your tokens/vectors
# you can add it as a new column in your dataframe
np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=-1)

OUT:  
array([0.88986344, 0.65811907, 1.09766282, 1.13475447])
```